# I always go in first, and come out last. What am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I always go in first, and come out last. What am I?
[It's from a Swarovski crystal game I'm playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqqal.png)

Comment: This may well rely on details or circumstances specific to the game you are playing, and as such is not something that can be “self-contained” here on this site. Likewise, if the answers requires specific knowledge from the game, any answers posted here are very likely to be speculative unless the answerer already knows the game answer (or can test it themselves). How confident are you that this answer does not inherently require knowledge of/from the game to answer it?

Comment: Is it the first element in a stack? As in Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, I don't think this is speculative. It's key.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> a key

because

> you need to put it in the lock first to unlock the door, and you also need to remove it from the lock after you locked it.

Answer (score 1):

A

> trash bag

because it's the first thing

> you put in the trash can

and the last thing

> to come out when you empty it.